# repair command in mongodb in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

My client has mongodb running in docker container, one morning the db crashed and logs says "unclean shutdown detected". I tried for repairing mongodb but not able to do as it is running under docker container. The reason is that as i have to shutdown mongodb for running repair command and once i shutdown the mongodb then docker throws me out of the container because only one process was running and as it was stopped container was also stopped, now i am not able to run any mongod commands as i am out of container and container is stopped along with mongod instance.

So, can anyone help me out of this, how can i run repair command from outside of docker container ?

Can i run repair command without stopping mongod ?

Please help !!!

Thanks
Irshad

Comment: What Image are you using? It might be possible to run `docker run -it -v data:data mongoimage mongo_repair` (I don't know whtat the repair command actually is)

Comment: I ran below command and it worked 

"sudo docker run -it -p 28000:27017 --name <containername> mongo:latest mongod --dbpath <dbpath> --repair" 

Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: it worked for me as well, thank you

Answer (score 16):

The example command below fixed my issue with corrupted Wt files.

```
docker run -it -v <path>:/data/db <image-name> mongod --repair
```

Just replace path and image-name with yours

Comment: can you provide more information, how you tried and what errors you got?

Comment: what is `<path>` here?

Comment: the ":" operator maps the left operand a.k.a. folder to the right. That means <path> is the location of the mongo /data/db folder that you store permanently on your disk for later use by the container. On the right is the <path> inside the container. Mongodb expects to be /data/db that's why is hardcoded

Comment: for docker-compose use ``docker-compose run mongo mongod --repair``

Answer (score 2):

I had this same thing when my Mac decided to restart and install an update this morning, grr.

Normally my mongo container is started with a `docker-compose up` command, which uses a `docker-compose.yml` file for all the settings, something like...

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6.12
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
     - 27017:27017
    volumes:
     - ~/mongo/data/db:/data/db
     - ~/mongo/db/configdb:/data/configdb
```

To run a basic `docker` command with those settings I did...

```sh
# Kill any existing mongo containers
docker rm mongo

# Repair the db
docker run -it -v ~/mongo/data/db:/data/db -v ~/mongo/db/configdb:/data/configdb --name mongo -d mongo:3.6.12  mongod --repair

# Has it finished the repair yet?
docker ps -a
```

After about a minute the container exited, the database was repaired and I was able to run mongo using `docker-compose` again.

Comment: i have same problem and mongod --repair not work not correct version 

this is good work

# Repair the db
docker run -it -v <path_in_host>:<path_in_contaoiner --name mongo -d <docker-compose-image>  mongod --repair

Answer (score 1):

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    command: --repair
```

This is how we pass the --repair in docker-compose.